# Boxee: Remove the standard overlay if pressing pause?

Tags: boxee

Is there any way how I can remove the pause overlay in the boxee player? I need to trigger the button, but i don t want the pause overlay to appear automatically. Or is this unchangeable?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this isn t an issue anymore after the last boxee update!